# Recoding NAs conditional on multiple columns in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a lot of survey data where respondents were asked many different multiple-choice questions for which they could choose multiple answers. The survey software coded each question as multiple variables that could have values of either the answer or NA. NA isn't really appropriate, though, as, unless the individual skipped the question, not selecting an answer really means "no." I want to re-code all the questions of this type to fix this so I can analyze the data. If the individual skipped the questions the NAs should stand, but if they clicked at least one of the multiple choices, then the NAs should be "no"s.
Example below:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(SC_1 = c("yes", "yes", NA, "yes", "yes", NA, "yes", "yes", NA, "yes"),
             SC_2 = c("yes", NA, NA, NA, "yes", "yes", NA, "yes", NA, "yes"),
             RF_1 = c("gas", "gas", NA, "gas", "gas", NA, "gas", "gas", NA, "gas"),
             RF_2 = c("electricity", NA, NA, NA, "electricity", "electricity", NA, "yes", NA, "electricity"))
```

I could do this by taking each question one at a time

```
df %>% mutate(SC_1_recode = ifelse(is.na(SC_1) & is.na(SC_2), SC_1, 
                                   ifelse(is.na(SC_1),"no", SC_1)),
              SC_2_recode = ifelse(is.na(SC_1) & is.na(SC_2), SC_2, 
                                   ifelse(is.na(SC_2),"no", SC_2)),
              RF_1_recode = ifelse(is.na(RF_1) & is.na(RF_2), RF_1, 
                                   ifelse(is.na(RF_1),"no", RF_1)),
              RF_2_recode = ifelse(is.na(RF_1) & is.na(RF_2), RF_2, 
                                   ifelse(is.na(RF_2),"no", RF_2)))

#   SC_1  SC_2  RF_1  RF_2        SC_1_recode SC_2_recode RF_1_recode RF_2_recode
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
# 1 yes   yes   gas   electricity yes         yes         gas         electricity
# 2 yes   NA    gas   NA          yes         no          gas         no         
# 3 NA    NA    NA    NA          NA          NA          NA          NA         
# 4 yes   NA    gas   NA          yes         no          gas         no         
# 5 yes   yes   gas   electricity yes         yes         gas         electricity
# 6 NA    yes   NA    electricity no          yes         no          electricity
# 7 yes   NA    gas   NA          yes         no          gas         no         
# 8 yes   yes   gas   yes         yes         yes         gas         yes        
# 9 NA    NA    NA    NA          NA          NA          NA          NA         
#10 yes   yes   gas   electricity yes         yes         gas         electricity
```

But that seems cumbersome, given that I have dozens of this kind of question and they all have this problem.
Any ideas? I've been trying out `mutate_if()`, but haven't gotten anywhere.

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If we are doing this for multiple columns, one option is to reshape into 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and apply the function

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
f1 <- function(x) case_when(all(is.na(x))~ NA_character_,
            is.na(first(x)) ~ "no", 
              TRUE ~  first(x))
df %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c(".value", "group"), names_sep = "_")%>%
  group_by(rn) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(SC:RF), f1) %>% 
  ungroup %>%      
  filter(group == 1) %>%
  select(SC:RF) %>% 
  rename_all(~ str_c(., "_1_recode")) %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)
# A tibble: 10 x 6
#   SC_1  SC_2  RF_1  RF_2        SC_1_recode RF_1_recode
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
# 1 yes   yes   gas   electricity yes         gas        
# 2 yes   <NA>  gas   <NA>        yes         gas        
# 3 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>        <NA>        <NA>       
# 4 yes   <NA>  gas   <NA>        yes         gas        
# 5 yes   yes   gas   electricity yes         gas        
# 6 <NA>  yes   <NA>  electricity no          no         
# 7 yes   <NA>  gas   <NA>        yes         gas        
# 8 yes   yes   gas   yes         yes         gas        
# 9 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>        <NA>        <NA>       
#10 yes   yes   gas   electricity yes         gas
```

---

The dataset can also be split into different groups of dataset based on the column names and apply the function

```
library(purrr)
df %>% 
    split.default(str_remove(names(.), "_\\d+$")) %>% 
    map_dfc(~ 
          .x %>% 
              transmute(!! str_c(names(.)[1], "_1_recode") := 
                coalesce(!!! .) %>% 
                  replace(., !is.na(.) & is.na(!! rlang::sym(names(.)[1])), "no"))) %>%
    bind_cols(df, .)
```